# Issue select statement on excel sheet without using OLEDB provider

Tags: c#, sql, excel

How can I use a select statement on an Excel sheet without using any oledb Provider? This is what I got so far by using `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`. Iterating through each cell using a nested for-loop feels wrong...

```
// Create excel application object by calling constructor 
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

// Open excel file using excel object 
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Temp\file.xls");

// Open first sheet within excel document (index start at 1, not 0) 
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets["SheetName"];

// Get used sheet bounderies 
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

// Get row count 
int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;

// Get column count 
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

//iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
    {
        //new line
        if (j == 1)
            Console.Write("\r\n");

        //write the value to the console if cell value ends on 'd'
        if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null && (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString()).EndsWith("d"))
            Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it feel wrong? you are doing something different for each row, and then testing each column, you need a nested loop. BTW, you can move the newline output above the inside `for` and just put `Console.WriteLine();` there instead of testing `j`.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use the `items` interface to a range to go over all the cells, you are outputting for each row and conditionally outputting across columns, `for` is the right approach.

However, you could tighten the code up a little:

```
var rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
var colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; ++row) {
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; ++col) {
        //write the value to the console if cell value ends on 'd'
        if (xlRange.Cells[row, col]?.Value2?.ToString().EndsWith("d") ?? false)
            Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[row, col].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
    }
}
```